# SSH from master Jenkins docker container to child Jenkins container on a different machine

Tags: docker, jenkins, google-cloud-platform

I have two VMs on GCP in same network and same subnet. VM-A & VM-B, VM-A hosts a master Jenkins container & VM-B hosts a child Jenkins container. I need to SSH directly to child container from master Jenkins. Again both docker containers are on different machines. Any idea how can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but since both the containers are on VMs which are in the same network and subnet, wouldn't the container internal IPs also be in the same subnet? At least that's how I believe GCP networking works. If they indeed are in the same subnet, then you can SSH to the child container by specifying the internal IP of the child container.

Comment: I saw the containers private ips are totally different from the cidr range of subnet.

Comment: What about the private IPs cidr of the containers?
Also, are you running docker on both the VMs? Is there a connection between the two docker engines?

Comment: both containers have same private ips 172.16.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a container it sits in it's own docker network.

Only containers sitting in the same network can communicate directly using their network names.

Docker has [overlay networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-overlay/) using swarm but it is for non-prod environments.

As jenkins level solution , I use my external IP of the master to setup master-agent communication. Of course, it is less efficient.

Comment: thanks for the comment @lftimie. Can you a bit more specific on setting up master-agent communication? Like sharing the steps or any tutorial on how to do that?

Comment: As steps , you need to add ssh client and server in your containers, to expose port 22 , to allow port 22 to pass from VM hosting master to the VM hosting Agent and to setup ssh keys. This is a ssh tutorial but you will have to adapt it to docker . https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-openssh-server/. I would ask why do you need ssh from master to agent ? Maybe jenkins already has another solution to your problem using a plugin or a pipeline code

Comment: I need to do it for a CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: I am sorry - too general for me , can you detail the build step and the technology where you need to use ssh ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some docs which can be helpful. [SSH Credentials Management with Jenkins](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/222838288-SSH-Credentials-Management-with-Jenkins) and  [Using Jenkins agents](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-agents/). Do let us know if it was useful.